# How to get uncompressed length of GZIP-compressed string?

Tags: gzip, gzipstream

Is there any reliable way of getting the uncompressed length of a compressed string (specifically compressed with GZIP) without decompressing the string? I have no control over the compression process, i.e. no agreed upon flags or tail data. I've read you can check the four last bytes, but that seem to require flags to be enabled which, again, I have no control over.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/828300/85927

Comment: This does not answer my question. I need a reliable (read: tool independent, based only on the compression method) way to do this.

Comment: It provides as much of an answer as is possible without seeing your actual gzip string.  TL;DR; the gzip stream itself does not contain the information you require. But if your stream includes a header, it might.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks. Add it as an answer if you'd like me to accept it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9727599/1180620 .

Answer (score 0):

The gzip stream itself does not contain the information you require. But if your stream includes a header, it might.

More info [here](https://superuser.com/a/828300/85927).